# How can I tell what process is unmounting a file system?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel

I am trying to troubleshoot [an issue](https://github.com/bazil/fuse/issues/89) with a fuse library, where it appears that someone is causing my file system to be unmounted soon after it is mounted.

Does anybody have any clever ideas how I can snoop on who is telling the kernel to unmount the file system? I've attempted to use a Linux port of dtrace to find all calls to umount(2), but [it freezes the whole VM](https://github.com/dtrace4linux/linux/issues/114), or at least ssh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by replacing `/bin/mount` with a shell script that logged evidence (time, arguments, parent process) to a file. Turns out the file system was being rudely [unmounted by systemd](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=90907).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use the [inotify tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki)? [Here are some examples](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki) on how to use them. One of the events you can monitor is unmount.

If the unmounting is immediate, isn't it more probably that 'something' (not someone) is telling to unmount? Maybe missing privileges?